# CVS Bridge to SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, migration, cvs

I know there is [TortoiseCVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/), but I'm wondering if there is an easy way of sucking down source code in a CVS repository, just using SVN tools (without having to install CVS tools).

Since SVN seems to have taken the preferred spot in OSS, I have to believe somebody has written a tool that will map CVS databases to SVN repositories.

**EDIT**
Based on a few responses, while migrating off of CVS to SVN is cool, mostly I'm looking for a way for me to use my SVN client to pull from a CVS database with little or no fuss, much like you can do with [SVNBridge](http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge) (a real-time SVN bridge to TFS).

Comment: Thanks for the comment... Past CSV pain has apparently left a big scar!

Comment: OK, and I understand this as asking for a tool that allows SVN to act as a front end for CVS (rather than a tool that converts a CVS repository into an SVN repository once), right?

Comment: Right - something that would convert, on-the-fly CVS databases to look like SVN Repositories.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the CVS repository, you can use [cvs2svn](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/):

> cvs2svn is a tool for migrating a CVS repository to Subversion or git. The main design goals are robustness and 100% data preservation. cvs2svn can convert just about any CVS repository we've ever seen, including gcc, Mozilla, FreeBSD, KDE, GNOME...
>
> cvs2svn infers what happened in the history of your CVS repository and replicates that history as accurately as possible in the target SCM. All revisions, branches, tags, log messages, author names, and commit dates are converted. cvs2svn deduces what CVS modifications were made at the same time, and outputs these modifications grouped together as changesets in the target SCM. cvs2svn also deals with many CVS quirks and is highly configurable.

If you just want to pull the source code down from the repository, you can use the [CVS binaries](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/) to do that, without having to install TortoiseCVS.

Comment: Nice link, but is there anything that allows "real-time" pulling of CVS data?  CodePlex has [SVNBridge](http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge) for SVN clients connecting to their [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server).

Comment: I see.  You may want to modify your question to clarify that, since the phrase "map CVS databases to SVN repositories" sounds like you want to convert the repository from CVS to SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the difficulty of doing this as I have attempted to cross an older project of mine into SVN and eventually discarded my version data for a fresh start from a new repository.

Since that time other tools have become available, one of which is cvs2svn from tigris.

The product is linux environment and as such Cygwin (to compile) if you work from a Windows environment exclusively. There is a blog I found here which details one users experiences from a windows machine:

http://ruthklempel.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/migrating-cvs-to-svn-with-cvs2svn-basics-for-a-windows-user/

Good luck...